# How to write 1½-inch with SIUNITX

Tags: siunitx

Here is my attempt to write 1½-inch with `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{quotient-mode = fraction}
\begin{document}
\SI[number-unit-product=\text{-}]{1}{inch}\\
\SI[fraction-function=\sfrac]{1/2}{inch}\\
\SI[fraction-function=\sfrac,number-unit-product=\text{-}]{1/2}{inch}\\
\SI[fraction-function=\sfrac,number-unit-product=\text{-}]{1{}1/2}{inch}\\
\SI[fraction-function=\sfrac,number-unit-product=\text{-}]{1 1/2}{inch}\\
\num{1}\SI[fraction-function=\sfrac,number-unit-product=\text{-}]{1/2}{inch}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there not a more correct way to do it, instead of using `\num` and `\SI` together?

Comment: Not using `siunitx` at all? This is completely out of the scope of the package.

Comment: I know, BUT if I want to use `siunitx` what then? :-)

Comment: The most correct way to write that thing is *not* using `siunitx`: it essentially violates all the rules `siunitx` is based on.

Comment: So like this instead: `$1\sfrac{1}{2}$-inch`

Comment: @TobiasDK This is a bit like asking how to cut an apple with a chain saw. You just don't do it, because it is not how you do it. Why do you want to use `siunitx` to write something down that clearly doesn't follow the SI rules?

Comment: A more correct way would be `\SI{38.1}{\mili\metre}`, but that is not your question.

Comment: While I like SI/metric units much much more than the imperial ones, in engineering things like "1 1/2 in" for bore sizes of pipes are pretty common, even if imperial units are not used at all (like here in Germany). The DN system for bores is here not more intuitive or better to use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_Pipe_Size So for pipe bores, it would be nice, if siunitx would support the requested format as well.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: Expressing a length in millimeters rather than inches is not "more correct". No unit of measurement is more correct than any other unless a task requires one unit or the other.

Comment: @jvriesem siunitx has its name very likely from SI, millimeter is an SI unit, inch is not an SI unit, it isn't even a unit, so millimeter are more correct at least when you use siunitx. Since there are many different, incompatible, definitions of Inch, using millimeter is also more correct outside of siunitx. millimeter is an international accepted, well defined standard, inch isn't. Saying millimeter is not more correct than inch is like saying writing "computer" is not more correct than writing "asoidpjf" instead.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: Although definitions varied a hundred years ago, a standardized and exact definition of the inch exists based on the metric system: 25.4 mm = 1 inch. Therefore, the inch is (by definition) just as much a unit of length as the millimeter. A group's non-acceptance of the inch doesn't invalidate it as a unit used by others. Using the SI system over any other well-defined measurement system is in general no more "correct" than using one programming language over another. Different tools for different jobs: *context means everything*. I don't follow your last sentence.

Comment: @jvriesem There are still many different definitions of a inch (One example is the 寸, which is often named as (chinese) Inch and is defined as 1/30 m and still used in Taiwan). Inch does not belong to any well defined measurement system. It is also not a system, it is an historically grown mess. My point in the last sentence is: In a absolute sense you may can not say one is more correct than the other, because both are arbitrary defined, but one uses a well known, widely accepted definition (eg. SI system or the English language) and the other does not.

Comment: Another thing to note is that the SI brochure (and NIST) recommend against putting a hyphen between number and unit, as the space exists to denote multiplication. Other sources allow for this (including the PRL style guide) so it's not a universal no-no, but since I stumbled on this it feels worth noting (and also because I personally hate the practice)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does this qualify?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{quotient-mode = fraction}
\begin{document}
\SI[fraction-function=\sfrac]{1/2}[1]{inch}

\SI[fraction-function=\sfrac]{44/100}[99\;\!]{\%} pure
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this will do :-)
From `siunitx`: `\SI[options]{number}[pre-unit]{unit}`. So pre-unit will work as a number. Thank you.

Edit: to get the hyphen: `\SI[fraction-function=\sfrac,number-unit-product=\text{-}]{1/2}[1]{inch}`.
url: http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/numbers/hyphens-with-numbers/